# Booking tours from Sorrento for Pompeii et al

Tags: italy, bookings, naples, pompeii, sorrento

How easy is it from Sorrento to book tours for Pompeii and/or other attractions (Positano, Salerno)?

(edited on "may the fourth be with you" 2015)

We are currently in Sorrento and have booked a tour of Capri and will take the local bus (with a day pass) to Positano and Amalfi.

I did not fully recognized Sorrento as being a bristling tourist town.

Sorry if I was previously unclear.
Max.

Comment: From Sorrento you can easily visit those places on your own.  Are you only interested in guided tours, or pre-planned bus/train trips, or...?

Comment: As @JohnZwinck says, the question as it stands is fairly unclear. What do you mean by tours? Is it a logistics problem? Do you need help on how to get to places? Or are you talking about how to buy tickets for must-see sites? Or do you mean organised tours?